# Managing DI for Couchbase client

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ravendb, couchbase

With `RavenDb` it was really a piece of cake:

```
public class DataAccessModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IDocumentStore>().ToMethod(
            context => {
                var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {
                    DataDirectory = @"~/App_Data/database",
                    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
                };
                return documentStore.Initialize();
            }
       ).InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(context =>
            context.Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession()
        ).InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

How does one manage dependency injection for `Couchbase .NET client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/current), under the heading "Instantiating the Client":

> In practice, it's expensive to create clients.  The client incurs overhead as it creates connection pools and sets up the thread to get cluster configuration.  Therefore, the best practice is to create a single client instance, per bucket, per AppDomain.

Unlike RavenDB, it does not appear that CouchDB has a "session" or other unit-of-work container that has to be instantiated per request.

Therefore, if you want to use a DI container like Ninject, you would just register the `CouchbaseClient` class as a singleton, probably using the `ICouchbaseClient` interface.

```
Bind<ICouchbaseClient>().ToMethod(
        context => {
            var client = new CouchbaseClient();
            // do anything else you need to init the client here
            return client;
        }
   ).InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: It is correct that there is no analogous unit of work with the Couchbase client.  A singleton, per app domain, per bucket is the recommended way to maintain instances.